# How to check if a dataframe contains a certain element?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame named `df` , and I want to know the `df` whether contains the element `a` in each row.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
df=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3],'item1':['a','c','a'],
'item2':['b','d','e'],'item3':['c','e',np.nan]})
```

`Input:`

```
   id item1 item2 item3
0   1     a     b     c
1   2     c     d     e
2   3     a     e   NaN
```

In the new column `contain_a` , `1` represents the column `item1` or `item2` or `item3` contains the element `a` .

`Expected:`

```
   id item1 item2 item3 contains_a
0   1     a     b     c         1
1   2     c     d     e         0
2   3     a     e   NaN         1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
In [578]: df['contains_a'] = df.filter(like='item').eq('a').any(1).astype(int)

In [579]: df
Out[579]:
   id item1 item2 item3  contains_a
0   1     a     b     c           1
1   2     c     d     e           0
2   3     a     e   NaN           1
```

Answer (score 1):

Check each column barring `id` in column 1 (`df.iloc[:, 1:]`) using the string accessor to see if it contains the letter `a`, and then use `any` along the rows (`axis=1`).  Convert the boolean result to an integer (1 or 0).

```
>>> df.assign(contains_a=df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(lambda s: s.str.contains('a')).any(axis=1).astype(int))
   id item1 item2 item3  contains_a
0   1     a     b     c           1
1   2     c     d     e           0
2   3     a     e   NaN           1
```

Too make this more general for multiple targets:

```
targets = ['aa', 'a', 'b', 'c']
d = {'contains_{}'.format(target): 
         df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(lambda s: s.str.contains(target)).any(axis=1).astype(int)
     for target in targets}

>>> df.assign(**d)
   id item1 item2 item3  contains_a  contains_aa  contains_b  contains_c
0   1     a     b     c           1            0           1           1
1   2     c     d     e           0            0           0           1
2   3     a     e   NaN           1            0           0           0
```

Comment: Hi, if I have several elements to deal with, maybe using `contains_a` as keyword is not a good idea. Any suggestions?